# bash script for conditional grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I Have a json file in the following format, I want to write a bash script to perform an action on id if errorCode is 1.

if errorCode is 1 perform operation on id else do nothing

```
[{
    "endTime": null, 
    "errorCode": 1, 
    "id": 219759099, 
}, 

{
    "endTime": null, 
    "errorCode": 0, 
    "id": 219759100, 
}, 

{
   "endTime": null, 
    "errorCode": 0, 
    "id": 219759101, 
}]
```

Comment: Try using a `JSON` parser and perform what operation?

Comment: i have to do it in bash, operation1 can be any linux command.

Comment: What do you mean by `bash`? By using only `bash` built-ins or any tools/languages commonly found in a UNIX CLI environment.

Comment: Using Shell. somthing like grep the errorCode first, if it matches '1' write the value of id in a file.

Comment: This script https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh can help you parsing JSON in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick :

```
parity=0
for val in $(grep -E "errorCode|id" x.json|grep -Eo [0-9]+)
do
    if [ $parity -eq 0 ]
    then
            if [ $val -eq 1 ]
            then
            parity=1
            fi
    else
            echo "id $val is erroneous"
            parity=0
    fi
done
```

*where x.json is the jason file*.Replace the line containing *echo* command with a suitable statement as per your requirement. For example, if you are appending the id to a error log, try :

```
echo $val >> erroneousIDs.log
```

NB : I assumed that the ordering of the fields will always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a language with a proper `JSON` parser like `python`. Give a valid `JSON` file like:

```
[
    {
        "endTime": null,
        "errorCode": 1,
        "id": 219759099
    },
    {
        "endTime": null,
        "errorCode": 0,
        "id": 219759100
    },
    {
        "endTime": null,
        "errorCode": 0,
        "id": 219759101
    }
]
```

You can use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json

try:
    json_data=open(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    sys.stderr.write("Please provide a JSON file.\n")
    sys.exit(1)

data = json.load(json_data)

for d in data:
    if d["errorCode"] == 1:
        print d["id"]
```

Save it to a file and make it executable and run like:

```
$ ./get_ids.py file
219759099
```

You could pipe this into your `operation` command or extend the script to do the operation.

Comment: +1 for proper JSON parser. @shivam, note "a *valid* JSON file" -- cannot have a trailing comma before a close brace.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look at **[this](https://gist.github.com/cjus/1047794)** for a more robust approach. It uses sed and awk though to parse JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '[ ":,]+' '$2=="errorCode" && $3==1{err=1} err && $2=="id"{print $3; err=0}' f.json
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
219759099
```

Though I must caution that parsing JSON using shell is not the best way of parsing JSON and it might be error prone as well if JSON file's format changes.